# how should we validate http header referrer in aspx .net

Tags: asp.net, validation, referrer, http-referer

I want to ensure ensure nothing untoward gets into the referrer on an error page.

What should I be checking in order to validate the http header.

below is my current code:

```
// Ensure the referrer header is good
if (this.Request.UrlReferrer.IsWellFormedOriginalString() &&
    this.Request.UrlReferrer.Host.Equals(this.Request.Url.Host))
{
```

this will fail an acunetix scan that uses %3C and %3E instead of < and > for example so I obviously need to cover html encoding - is there anything else I am missing?

**Update**
I can catch all the acunetix scans using the code below:

```
if (this.Request.UrlReferrer.IsWellFormedOriginalString() &&
    this.Request.UrlReferrer.Host.Equals(this.Request.Url.Host) &&
    !Regex.IsMatch(this.Request.UrlReferrer.ToString(),
                   "%3C",
                   RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
{
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to ensure ensure nothing untoward gets into the referrer on an error page.

Then always HTML-escape any string — including referrer URLs — that you output to the error page.

Trying to pick out and blacklist input containing potentially dangerous characters on a case-by-case basis is doing it backwards. You probably won't catch all possible attacks, and you'll unnecessarily disallow valid URLs. (It's perfectly reasonable to have a URL with ‘%3C’ in.)

Answer (score 0):

this.Request.UrlReferrer may be null, if no referrer was provided or has participated.

Comment: true - i haven't included the full code here but i do check for null before i reach the code above